# Add '+' sign to integer subtraction operation result

Tags: java

I am performing subtraction operation in my code, and convert the received result to string. The result could be grater than 0 or negative. In case of negative result the '-' is automatically added to the result string.

I need to add the '+' sign, If i received possitive result. Please, advise me the most simple way to do that.

My code:

```
return String.valueOf(settlingScoreMap.get(market.getSettlingScore()).getAway()
          - settlingScoreMap.get(market.getSettlingScore()).getHome());
```

Comment: Is there a need to look up `settlingScoreMap.get(market.getSettlingScore())` twice or could you use a variable to simplify your code ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey. Hi. I can use variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `String.format`:

```
String.format("%+d", theIntValueToPrint)
                ^ This indicates that the sign should be added.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x=5;
        int y=3;
        int result=x-y;
        if (result<=0) 
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(result));
        else
            System.out.println("+"+String.valueOf(result));
```

Comment: Neither of the `String.valueOf`s are needed here. In the first case, `println(int)` can be called; in the second case, "+"+result automatically coerces `result` to a string.

Comment: Yes Andy , String.valueOf s are not needed  for this example . But if i assign value as a String and use. For example : String resultString;
  if (result<=0) 
   resultString=String.valueOf(result);
  else
   resultString="+"+String.valueOf(result);

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int val1 = 5;
    int val2 = 4;

    int result = val1 - val2;

    System.out.println(result > 0 ? "+" + result : String.valueOf(result));
}
```